# Laravel migration to edit existing table data

Tags: laravel, migration

I'm very much new to Laravel and backend, so I got quite lost here.
I need to loop through all the rows in a table and edit the data of a field based on a condition.

The field consists of a url and I want to add http at the start. I already have that function but I cant write the migration to loop through all the fields. Can anyone help?

I think I'm mainly having trouble accessing the table here.

```
public function up()
{
  Schema::table('firms', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $results = $table::where()->select('url')->get();
    foreach ($results as $urls) {
      $start = parse_url($urls->url, PHP_URL_SCHEME);
      if ($start !== 'http' && $start !== 'https') {
        $url = 'http://'.$urls->url;
        DB::table('firms')->where('url', $url)->update(['url' => $url]);
      }
      if ($start === 'http' || $start === 'https') {
        continue;
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I have a possibile solution, can you share the Firm table structure? and if is there a model related? Like App\Models\Firm

Comment: Why use a migration for this?

Comment: @brombeer not OP, but i had a situation where at some point all the developers in my team had to "fix" something due to a table structure change: we came up with a migration so everyone will call it wit artisan:migrate, instead of tell to everyone to fix the database

Comment: @Jack You could create an artisan command that does that and call that command instead. Once the migration has run it isn't easy to rerun it

Comment: @brombeer i agree with you. But, you have to call the command inside the migration then?

Comment: @Jack No, just call the command instead of `artisan:migrate`. Besides, the _structure_ hasn't changed, the content has

Comment: @brombeer again I agree with you, it's much more clear. But if your database is filled and your team is about 10 people, you have to tell everybody to run the command. In this case is done "automatically". I can understand why OP is doing this, that's said, it's not my business.

Comment: @Jack yes there is a model for Firm. I'm not sure what you mean by structure. would a visual like a screenshot from navicat help?

Comment: Few thoughts : 1. `if ($start === 'http' || $start === 'https') { continue;}`
is completely superfluous. 2. `DB::table('firms')->where('url', $url)->update(['url' => $url]);` is looking for the NEW value, so if this approach works (I don't know if it will) then it will not find the new value.  You want the previous line to be `$newurl = 'http://'.$urls->url;` and then use `DB::table('firms')->where('url', $url)->update(['url' => $newurl]);`

Comment: @GilesBennett, thanks for the response, I'll try to implement this logic, but the main thing I'm stuck on is connecting to the table correctly. Should I use Schema::table or DB::table ? What is the right way to get the data here?

Comment: If you've got a model, just use the model. Also, put the code outside the Schema::table() function, and just have it as standalone code within the up() function? It'll be executed nonetheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

**If you have Firm model:**

```
// looping only to firms which url field is not starting with http
foreach(Firm::where('field', 'value')->where('url', 'not like', 'http%')->get() as $firm){
    //updating single firm adding http://
    $firm->update(['url' => 'http://' . $firm->url]);
}

//or in just one line:
Firm::where('url', 'not like', 'http%')->update(['url' => DB::raw("CONCAT('http://', url)")]);
```

in this case `where('field', 'value')` is an optional other condition, you can remove it.

The first solution updates updated_at field, the second doesn't

**If you DON'T have Firm model:**

```
DB:raw("Update firms set url = CONCAT('http://', url) where url not like 'http%'");
```

as @brombeer pointed out, do it in an artisan command is much cleaner

Comment: Thank you very much @Jack, it worked! I removed the firs where clause because it threw an error " SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'field' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `firms` where `field` = value and `url` not like http%)"

Comment: That's why I added the comment that was optional. In your question you added a where() condition